# How to make Solr query returning results grouped by field

Tags: solr

I like to channel Solr search results at query time. For example I have three channels: `products`,  `faq` and `other_docs`. All within the same Solr core with the same fields filled. What I would like to acceive is to have Solr group the results "channel" for me.

Sample database (csv):

```
id,channel,name,desc
1,product,Some product,This is an very cool product!
2,product,Other product,This is an other product!
3,faq,How to stuff,This time: Simply do it!
4,other_docs,Legal notice,All your base are belong to us!
```

Wanted query result (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="grouped">
  <lst name="channel">
    <int name="matches">3</int>
    <arr name="groups">
      <lst>
        <str name="groupValue">product</str>
        <result name="doclist" numFound="2" start="0">
          <doc>
            <str name="name">Some product</str>
            <str name="desc">This is an very cool product!</str></doc>
          <doc>
            <str name="name">Other product</str>
            <str name="desc">This is an other product!</str></doc>
        </result>
      </lst>
      <lst>
        <str name="groupValue">faq</str>
        <result name="doclist" numFound="1" start="0">
          <doc>
            <str name="name">How to stuff</str>
            <str name="desc">This time: Simply do it!</str></doc>
        </result>
      </lst>
    </arr>
  </lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

**How do I acceive this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Field collapsing feature in SOLR

[Result Grouping / Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)

Comment: ah, I missed the `group.limit` option.